# Table: Minimize column width (multiple colspans)

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I have this:

[image: Source]

and want this (second column using less space):

[image: Target]

Is there a way without introducing absolute values or fixed columns? I don't mind any other hacks like wrappers or invisible columns as long as the content sizes dynamically.

**HTML**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: avenir;
  height: 100vh;
}

td > div {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px dotted white;
}

.w1px {
  width: 1px;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="w1px"><div>Item1</div></td>
      <td><div>Item2</div></td>
      <td><div>Item3</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><div>Item Spanning All Three Above</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div>Item Spanning Two</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="h-100">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: "as long as the content sizes dynamically" is too vague to know what you want

Comment: I want all columns to take the minimum amount of space needed to contain the text that is in them without wrapping. Differently put: no matter which text you put into the cells above, there should never be extra space in a cell, which isn't needed to accomodate content of the column in a different row.